# Tkinter: Loading an existing excel file

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

I'm trying to open and load an existing excel file but it's not coming up. Any sugessions? No issue with modifying it while the file is closed; but how to load in Excel loader from Python?

```
import xlrd, xlwt

wb1 = xlrd.open_workbook('Station_Layout.xls', formatting_info=True)

aString = open('Station_Layout.xls','rb').read()
```

Comment: What does "not coming up" mean? Does the program crash? Do you get an error? What error? Is the data garbled? Empty?

Comment: Hello, I tried another solution and worked for me;;  import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("Station_Layout.xls")
excel.Visible = True

Comment: This link helps alot: http://pythonexcels.com/basic-excel-driving-with-python/